# RDD Pipe operation converts each Row to a string. How to convert back to row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am using PySpark to pipe an RDD out to an external process (stdin/stdout).

```
piped_rdd = rdd.pipe(exe_path)
```

When I examine the returned PipeLineRDD all rows have been converted to strings

```
["Row(ID='x123223=', FirstName='L', LastName='S')", "Row(ID='43454".....)]
```

Is it possible to convert these strings back into proper rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `eval()`. I tested the following which seems to work on the sample data.

```
val_ls = [
    "Row(ID='x123223=', FirstName='L', LastName='S')", 
    "Row(ID='x123224=', FirstName='K', LastName='P')"
]

def evalRow(theRowString):
    """
    imports pyspark.sql.Row and uses `eval()` to resolve the Row strings
    """
    from pyspark.sql import Row

    return eval(theRowString)

spark.sparkContext.parallelize(val_ls).map(lambda k: evalRow(k)).collect()
# [Row(ID='x123223=', FirstName='L', LastName='S'),
# Row(ID='x123224=', FirstName='K', LastName='P')]
```

I checked the `type` of the results

```
set(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(val_ls).map(lambda k: type(evalRow(k))).collect())
# {pyspark.sql.types.Row}
```

---

I was initially just importing `Row` without creating the function and used `eval()` directly in the `map()` --

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(val_ls).map(lambda k: eval(k)).collect()
```

I kept hitting the error `NameError: name 'Row' is not defined`. I think it is because we aren't importing `Row` on the workers and it does not know how to evaluate the `eval("Row(...)")`

Comment: This looks like it should work. And I can see row types on my side. What I want to do is be able to create a dataframe from the resultant RDD. It's not working for me, I am getting 'SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument' when I try to do anything with the derived dataframe, but that's another problem for me.